# Some scripts don't display correctly in JPanel, even when encoded in UTF-8?

Tags: java, utf-8, character-encoding, jpanel

So I'm just making this little Java application for myself which is meant to deal with different languages (though which languages yet, I don't know), which means that it should be able to handle different scripts. The problem is that it seems as though certain scripts (Burmese, for example) don't display correctly. The following image shows what I mean:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1WQ52.png

As you can see, most scripts seem to work fine, even more obscure ones such as Georgian and more complicated ones such as Chinese. But other scripts don't display correctly. Is there a way to work around this?

For info, this is the exact process I go through to display the above picture:

1) Reading from a .txt file (the .txt file is encoded in UTF-8, and all the different scripts appear just fine) as so:

```
try {
    fis = new FileInputStream("text file as path");
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
try {
    br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis,"UTF8"));
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
    //more stuff...
try {
    while((lineStr = br.readLine()) != null){
        //Store lineStr in a String[] array...
    }
    br.close()
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

2) Once the lines are in a String[] variable (called "linesArray"), I display them in the JPanel:

```
JLabel[] labels = new JLabel[linesArray.length];
String labeltext = new String();
for(int i=0;i<linesArray.length;i++){                   
    labeltext = String.format("<html><div WIDTH=%d>%s</div><html>", 139, linesArray[i]);
    labels[i] = new JLabel(labeltext);
    labels[i].setForeground(Color.RED);
    //set bounds and add to the JPanel
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Wild guess, but are you sure that font you are using contains characters you want to display?

Comment: Wow I feel so stupid now. I had assumed that the font would include them but it seems as though certain scripts (such as Burmese) aren't actually contained in the most common fonts. 

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like font you are using may not contain characters you want to display.